# Ajax Contact Form Script Doesn't Send the Message in the Email

Tags: php, ajax, email

So I have written a script in ajax that connects to a PHP mail() script to send an email to `info@example.com` (obviously replacing example.com with my domain) and the email sends fine, everything is setup except for one problem:

```
     $.ajax({
        url:'contact.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: {
           name:name,
           email:email,
           message:message
          },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert("Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.");
        }
    })
    return false;
    event.preventDefault();
    })
```

The email I receive is formatted exactly as my contact.php states:

```
<?php
    $to = "info@example.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message =$_POST['message'];
    echo $_POST['test'];
    $subject = "Contact form from: ".$name;
    $body = 'Hello developer(s)!<br><br>
The following is a submission from the Contact Form on <a target="_blank" href="https://example.com">example.com</a>. Please respond using your own email (like info@example.com).<br><br>
Name: '.$name."<br>
Email: ".$from."<br>
Message: <br>".$message."<br><br>
Thank you!";
    $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$from."> \r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
    echo "Success!<br></br>";
?>
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Hello developer(s)!

The following is a submission from the Contact Form on example.com. Please respond using your own email (like info@example.com).

Name: Owen Sullivan
Email: sulliops@gmail.com
Message: 


Thank you!
```

Notice that the message is missing, even though a message has been submitted in the form. Any idea why this is the only part missing?

**EDIT:** This is the form code:

```
<form method="post" name="cform" id="cform" action="contact.php" class="contact-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name..." required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email..." required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message..." required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" class="submitBnt btn btn-custom" value="Send Message">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="simple-msg"></div>
</form>
```

**FIXED AJAX CODE:**

```
$.ajax({
        url:'contact.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize()
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert("Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.");
        }
    })
    return false;
    event.preventDefault();
    })
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "outputs"?Is it text that arrives to your email or what?

Comment: Your form element either has no name element, value, or has a different name than `message`. var_dump($_POST); and verify you actually are receiving a value.

Comment: Yes, when the email is sent, the Message field doesn't include the text that I wrote and submitted on the page with the form.

Comment: I added the form code, but I'm fairly sure I have the message box setup properly

Comment: On your ajax portion, where and how are you defining `message` to be used in the post data? You excluded where those js variables are being defined.

Comment: @Randall I thought I properly defined it in `data {}`

Comment: Showing us just `message:message` means that `message` is a js variable that was defined somewhere before your .ajax action (same with name, and email). Could you add that code to your snippet in the Q?

Comment: @Randall is it not in the `<form>` code? I don't think I defined the `name` or `email` variables anywhere else either, but they still work

Comment: They have to be defined somewhere ;) Are you using an abstraction layer on top of jquery that is auto-converting all form element ids into javascript variables for you? The javascript portion you have in your Q is missing some vital bits on how you are getting form data to the ajax action. Because missing the `message` in post is happening somewhere around there.

Comment: @Randall I have no idea, total beginner at this. I'm just modifying some code that my teammates wrote and they aren't sure what's going on either. I'm assuming that the ids are being auto-converted, but if that were the case, it should be working.

Comment: We are just guessing at this point, because the javascript you provided is incomplete (it even has 'event.', which doesnt exist in your paste)... so PLEASE add the full javascript code for your form submit handler!

Comment: @Randall _I don't know where the full javascript is_. All I did was modify some pre-existing code.

Comment: There should (hopefully) be `var message = ...etc.` in close proximity to the `$.ajax` javascript that you have posted. That is what you need to find to see how that message variable is extracting the textarea content from the form.

Comment: @Rasclatt no such code exists — should I add it? and if so, what code am I supposed to add?

Comment: Then you need need to do a search for `message` and find where (above the current ajax) that is assigned. You should have a `var email = ...`, a `var name  = ...` and a `var message = ...` above that ajax somewhere.

Comment: @Rasclatt once again, no such code exists. It seems that none of those have been defined _at all_. How do I need to define these three variables?

Comment: You may not see it, but it has to be defined because you are using the `data: { name:name, email:email, message:message }` in the ajax and if you are receiving the other fields, then they are being defined. Download your site (if you haven't already) and do a text search for `email` or `var email`, `message` or `var message`, and `name` or `var name`.

Comment: @Rasclatt I can view all the files right now, and I looked through all the JS files and everything — no `var email`, no `var name`, no `var message`. What's confusing me is that the name and email work fine when I submit the form, which leads me to believe that they are already defined properly somewhere (but I can't find where)

Comment: Then just change your ajax data to be `data: $(this).serialize()` instead of `{ name:name, email:email, message:message }`, that will resend the form in full.

Comment: Also, you will probably want to strip html out of the user input. A savvy user could manipulate your `mail()`. Use `strip_tags()` and possibly `htmlspecialchars()` on the message and name, then use `$is_valid_email = filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);` to check if the email is valid before you send the email. Also, maybe comment out `//dataType: 'json',` in the ajax and send just a regular request.

Comment: @Rasclatt I've added a **fixed** section to my original question, is that code what you mean? Or is `this` just a placeholder for something else? Regarding the rest of the code, I'll see about adding it, but right now I just want the whole form to be sent.

Comment: You need a comma after `data: $(this).serialize(),` and I would comment out `dataType: 'json',`, you aren't using `json`...that will serve to make things more complicated for now.

Comment: @Rasclatt okay, so I changed the code (and added that comma), commented out `dataType: 'json',`, but it still doesn't have the entered message text in the email

Comment: Is this a localhost or do you have a public-facing site to see this?

Comment: https://flashflow.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some changes I would suggest

```
// You have a syntax error on yours, you need a listener
$(document).ready(function() {
    /** Listen for submit **/
    $("#cform").on("submit",function(event) {
        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();
        // Send ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: 'contact.php',
            type: 'POST',
            // Serialize the form
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            // Remove the json
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert("Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then in your PHP would be something like:

```
    <?php
    $to      = "info@example.com";
    $from    = trim($_POST['email']);
    # Stop if you don't have a valid address
    if(!filter_var($from,FILTER_VALIDATED_EMAIL))
        die('Invalid email address.');
    # Strip out stuff from the submission
    $name    = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['name'])));
    $message = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['message'])));

    $subject = "Contact form from: ".$name;
    $body    = 'Hello developer(s)!<br /><br />
The following is a submission from the Contact Form on <a target="_blank" href="https://example.com">example.com</a>. Please respond using your own email (like info@example.com).<br><br>
Name: '.$name."<br>
Email: ".$from."<br>
Message: <br />".$message."<br /><br />
Thank you!";
    $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$from."> \r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    # You need to make a condition to make sure it does, in fact, send
    echo (mail($to,$subject,wordwrap($body, 70, "\r\n"),$headers))? 'Success!' : 'Failed to send message.';
```

---

---

**EDIT:**

> **NOTE:** You have two submissions for ajax, the one you are adding and the one in your `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` file starting at line `76`. You are duplicating your efforts on adding it again. You will want to edit that block...or remove it and build out the above.

Comment: okay, so first of all, even after I changed the email to match the email I want the response sent to, nothing is being sent/received. Second, how do I get rid of the popup? I just want it to use the Success! message that I had before.

Comment: Look at my edit, you are duplicating your scripts. The `message` and such that we've been talking about is in the `js/app.js` file...

Comment: I removed the duplicate from `app.js` but I'm still getting two emails (one with the message, one without). And I'm getting both the popup and the `Success!` message that appears on top of the form.

Comment: Clear your browser cache, reload the page. If you still get two after that, then you still have a dup somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to check where you are getting the value for the "message" `textarea`. Make sure you are using `.val()` or `.value`. You are probably using `.text()` on all of the form fields and it is failing for your `textarea`.

Comment: Good educated guess, unsure why the downvote though.

Comment: I have no idea why it's downvoted, I certainly didn't do that. It won't let me upvote it.

Comment: I only recently started posting on Stack Overflow. This is not the first answer I've submitted that was automatically downvoted...I'm not sure what the deal is.

Comment: I figured it out @totallyquiche — users with less than 15 rep start with -1 votes for some reason

Comment: Thanks, @OwenSullivan!